# .NET console app fails to execute class field initialization lines in Release builds

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a .NET console app that looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    private static SomeObject obj = Objmanager.GetObject();
    private static int foo = 1;

    // Other initializations...
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ...
        // Some code which uses obj;
        ...
    }
}
```

In Debug builds, the `private SomeObject obj = Objmanager.GetObject();` line is executed (so is `private int foo = 1;` along with any other initializations) and subsequent references to `obj` work as expected.

In Release builds however, none of the field initialization lines execute, so `obj` is never initialized and subsequent references to `obj` fail with a `NullReferenceException`.  I've verified this by stepping through the Release code.

However, when I access ANY of the other variables, e.g. `foo`, like this:

```
class Program
{
   private static SomeObject obj = Objmanager.GetObject();
   private static int foo = 1;
   // Other initializations...

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       ...
       // Access foo in any way, e.g. foo++;, Console.WriteLine(foo); etc.
       Console.WriteLine(foo);
       // Some code which uses obj - now it works fine!
       Console.WriteLine(obj);
       ...
   }
   }
```

Then ALL of the field initialization lines execute.

As stated previously, works as expected in Debug but gives this behavior in Release.

I feel as though it was previously working properly and at some point this problem started.

Comment: It is an optimization, google ".net beforefieldinit" to learn more.  Always favor posting correct repro code when you ask for help at SO.

Comment: Doesn't seem that surprising since those are instance fields on a class that **doesn't have** to be instantieted. I'm more surprised this works in debug.

Comment: @HansPassant - I will do that now.  Please clarify your second statement - this is correct repro code.

Comment: You cannot access an instance field in a static method.  Note how you confused the bejeezus out of the previous commenter.  Use static in your snippet, like you did in your real code.

Comment: upon closer inspection obj/foo shouldn't even be accessible in main.

Comment: @user6144226 Can you please clarify what doesn't have to be instantiated?  Second I was surprised here since I have always thought that instance fields MUST initialize before any other code in the class.

Comment: It can't be though because obj and foo are not static, but you're referring to them from a static function. Can you post a correct minimal example pointing out exactly what error is thrown where?

Comment: @Howiecamp `Program`'s `Main` method is static. Program is never instantiated. At least that's the case in the code you've posted.

Comment: @HansPassant and all - good catch on the correct repro code - I left off `static` on the variable declarations.

Comment: Is `GetObject` doing what you expect it to do in your Release build? It sounds like it's returning null.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris In the Release build that line isn't ever hit - that's my problem.

Comment: To all those hammering the hell out of me for making a mistake of leaving out static - I apologize.  I'm a bad human and don't need to be chastized.  It is there.  Yes I understand the value of putting correctly repro code. It was a mistake.

Comment: I have to ask: Are you setting the breakpoint within the `GetObject` method, or on the line where it is invoked? The compiler may have inlined the assignment.

Comment: Add static constructor to Program, can be empty (`static Program() {}`) - and fields will be initialized in release mode. As for why - Hans already answered in first comment (or rather - provided a way to find an answer).

Comment: @ChristopherHarris I set it on both just to make sure I was covered.  Neither executed.

Comment: That is odd. The only thing that comes to mind is that maybe the debugger is running an older/different version of your code than what you expect, but assuming it's for the source you're currently working on.

Comment: @HansPassant Per your suggestion I researched `beforefieldinit` and now understand the issue - it's a question of lazy/deferred initialization.  The fact that I haven't run into this problem before seems to be just luck.  If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: All again - I encourage the downvoters to remove the downvotes now that I've corrected my (horrible!) error, as the question and the root issue experienced is quite valid and could help others.

Comment: Learn something new every day.

Comment: We already have lots of Q+A about beforefieldinit behavior, 380 posts talk about it.  If you think you can add more useful knowledge then please consider posting the answer yourself to either this question or one of the existing ones.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok I'll do a duplicate question thing.  Unless I can't do it because I haven't got enough points.